# Sticking pedals problem

Tags: hybrid-bike

I have a Raleigh bicycle and am currently unable to rotate the pedals backwards while riding. The cassette gets stuck in the anti-clockwise direction. Could anyone tell me the solution?

Comment: Welcome! This might need some more detail to answer well. Can you start by adding some photos of the bike and the pedal area, chain and back wheel?

Comment: Need more details about the bike.  Could be that you have back-pedal brakes, but, if this is a derailleur bike, it's more likely that the chain is simply getting jammed somehow.

Comment: Also, if this bike is a multi-speed bike with a rear derailleur and a cassette with multiple gears on the rear, it's not really designed to be pedaled backwards at all. When you pedal forwards, the derailleur guides the chain onto the proper rear sprocket **and** keeps the chain under tension. When you pedal backwards, you pull the derailleur forward, loosening the chain, and all that loose chain is pushed back to the cassette with no guide.  The loose chain can wind up just about anywhere. It can go places it shouldn't, and it can get stuck and even damage things.

Comment: @AndrewHenle While that's true, a well-maintained derailleur system shouldn't have any problem being spun backwards.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your bike has a [back-pedal brake](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/coaster-brakes.html). When you pedal backwards and it gets stuck, goes the bike slow down as well?

Comment: Downvoted because the OP mentions a cassette and on the page you linked it says “A coaster brake is not compatible with derailer gearing or a chain tensioner.”

Answer (score 0):

You said "the cassette gets stuck" so it sounds like you have a freewheel sprocket on the back that won't freewheel. Most often I've seen this on bikes left outside in the rain and the freewheel rusts solid.
I can think of two options

1. Us a lightweight oil or something like a WD-40 to attempt to clean the inside of the freewheel and get it spinning again. If you use a something like WD-40 and you do get it spinning be sure to lubricate the freewheel with a light weight oil.
2. Replace the freewheel

A variation on option 2 is to use a different wheel with a different freewheel

Comment: You could test the bike with a borrowed rear wheel (same number of sprockets for obvious reason, of course) to see if the problems lies with you rear wheel.